# mobx-state-tree invalid type definition for property 'lessons', it looks like you passed on object

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react, mobx-state-tree, mobx-react-lite

This is the model that is expecting the lessons:

```
export const LessonModel = types.model({
    is_imported: types.boolean,
})

const CalendarStoreModel = types.model('newCalendarStore',{
    lessons: types.optional(types.array(LessonModel),[]),
     selectedDate: types.string
})
```

and here I am providing the lessons

```
const model = {
    lessons: [  
       {
        is_imported: false,
       }
    ],
    selectedDate: "2020-10-21"
}
```

Tried wrapping the lessons on LessonModel.create but it did not fix it.

Comment: [Your example seems to work nicely](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-lake-1dd0l?file=/src/index.js). Are you sure this is the data you are using to create the model with in your code?

Comment: The data being entered was correct but I am using types.compose to create the store. if I need it in the sandbox with the array I get the same error but if I do it without an array no error.

Comment: const NewCalendarStore = types.compose(
    'newCalendarStore',
    ApiStore,
    types.model('NewCalendar', model).actions(actions).views(views)
)

Comment: Was creating the store like this and if you refactor the sandbox example to use this instead you will get the same error.